# DeepAR converting timeseries array into JSON - (pandas, python)

Tags: python, json, pandas, anaconda, amazon-sagemaker

have really been banging my head on a wall about this.

Using DeepAR on AWS to make a model and hitting this problem.

Getting stuck on converting it to JSON so it can be ingested by DeepAR

```py
#defining my frequency, prediction length and context length for the predictions

freq = '1min'
prediction_length = 10
context_length = 60

start_dataset = pd.Timestamp("2017-01-01 01:00:00", freq=freq)
end_training = pd.Timestamp("2017-12-29 16:55:00", freq=freq)
```

Next comes the problem, converting to JSON

```py
training_data = [
    {
        "start": str(start_dataset),
        "target": ts[start_dataset:end_training].tolist()  
    }
    for ts in timeseries
]
print(len(training_data))

--> TypeError: cannot do slice indexing on <class 'pandas.core.indexes.range.RangeIndex'> with these indexers [2017-01-01 01:00:00] of <class 'pandas._libs.tslib.Timestamp'>
```

The array (timeseries), was made this way:

```py
timeseries = []
num_timeseries = fxdata.shape[1]
timeseries = []
for i in range(num_timeseries):
    timeseries.append(np.trim_zeros(fxdata.iloc[:,i], trim='f'))
```

Looks like this: [image]

The date_time column from the original data frame (this is some FOREX data) has been converted already using the following:

```py
df['date_time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date_time'],dayfirst=True)
```

Thank you in advance for any advice and help!

Comment: have you looked into ```df.to_json()```? https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_json.html

Comment: You know I tried that straight after posting and it worked ahahha, thanks for the reply! Think it'll be good for others who are trying to use SageMaker also.